# Related rates shadow question

Tags: calculus

A $5$ meter lamp is casting a shadow on a $1.8$ meter man walking away at $1.2$ meters a second, how fast is the shadow increasing?

I have no idea how to do this, it feels like there is missing information. I know that this is a problem about triangles but there is some weird trick that has to be used since only two heights are known which are both the same part of a triangle.

Comment: You might assume the man is next to the lamp at time zero, and then work out the length of the shadow when the time is  $t$ seconds later.

Comment: You are right about feeling there **might be** some missing information. (It so happens we are told all that is necessary, but that is not obvious.) If we have a circle and know how fast its radius is changing, and want to find how fast its *area* is changing, the answer depends also on the current radius (or area). But how fast its *circumference* is changing depends only on how fast radius is changing, because circumference is linear in the radius. Similarly, the length of the shadow is linear in the distance of the person from the base of the lamp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After $t$ seconds, the man has traveled $1.2t$ meters from the lamp. Let $\mathrm{shadow}(t)$ denote the length of the man's shadow after $t$ seconds.

[image]

Note that triangles $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle CDE$ are similar. Therefore the ratios between corresponding sides must be equal:
$$\frac{BC}{AB}=\frac{DE}{CD}$$
which tells us
$$\frac{1.2t}{3.2}=\frac{\mathrm{shadow}(t)}{1.8}$$
so that
$$\mathrm{shadow}(t)=\frac{1.2t}{3.2}\times 1.8=\frac{2.16 t}{3.2}=\frac{27t}{40}.$$
Therefore
$$\frac{d\,\mathrm{shadow}(t)}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{27t}{40}\right)=\frac{27}{40}\,\text{m/s}$$

Comment: More handiwork, I see! (+1) of my few votes left for the day.

Comment: I'm really liking my new Sharpie pens :)

Comment: What happened in the last line? You take the derivative at time = 1?

Comment: @Jordan: No. For any linear function
$$f(t)=at+b,$$
the derivative of $f$ with respect to $t$ is just $a$. That is, the function
$$\left(\frac{df}{dt}\right)(t)$$
that inputs a number $t$ and outputs the derivative of $f$ at time $t$ is the ***constant*** function $a$. The derivative of $\mathrm{shadow}(t)$ at ***any*** time $t$ is $\frac{27}{40}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x$ be the horizontal distance between the lamp and the man and let $s$ be the length of the shadow. Note that $\dfrac{dx}{dt} = 1.2$ and we are asked to find $\dfrac{ds}{dt}$. By similar triangles (draw a diagram), we have:
$$
\dfrac{1.8}{5} = \dfrac{s}{s+x} \iff 1.8s+1.8x=5s \iff 3.2s=1.8x \iff s = \dfrac{9}{16}x
$$
Hence, by taking the derivative of both sides with respect to $t$, we obtain:
$$
\dfrac{ds}{dt} = \dfrac{9}{16}\dfrac{dx}{dt} = \dfrac{9}{16}(1.2) = \dfrac{27}{40} \text{m/s}$$

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there's any missing information here.  At any given time $t$, we can construct two similar triangles as follows:

Let $A$ be the top of the man, let $B$ be at the man's feet, and let $C$ be the edge of his shadow.  Let $A'$ be the top of the lamppost and let $B'$ be the bottom of the lamppost.  We note that the triangles $ABC$ and $A'B'C$ are similar.

Now, let $s(t)$ be the length of the man's shadow, and let $x(t)$ be the distance of the man from the lamppost.  By the above, we have the proportion

$$
\frac{5\,m}{1.8\,m}=\frac{x(t)+s(t)}{s(t)} = 1+\frac{x(t)}{s(t)}
$$

That should be enough to let you deduce the nature of $s(t)$, the movement of the shadow.